# Problem With Custom Scrollbar Text Cutoff

Tags: html, css, web, javascript, jquery

I am currently working on making a photography website for my good friend. I have employed the custom jScrollPane scrollbars from Kelvin Luck over at www.kelvinluck.com.

However, I am having some problems.

The temporary website is hosted here: http://phr-clan.com/nikka/index.php  You'll see the lovely scrollbars in action.  But, there's a problem. Scroll down all the way to the bottom and you'll see that the text is being cutoff before you can scroll all the way to the bottom.  It turns out that there is actually around a full couple paragraphs that aren't being displayed.  And the ironic thing is that it displays correctly in IE6 (Isn't it usually the other way around?)

Anyway, what am I doing wrong?  Here is my CSS file: http://phr-clan.com/nikka/styles.css

Help is greatly appreciated.  I have been pulling my hair wondering why it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
p.text {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'DISCORegular';
  font-size: 19px;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```